# Connection pool vs JNDI data source pooling

Tags: java, tomcat, jndi, connection-pooling, apache-commons-dbcp

There are two ways to get connection pooling:

- via server `JNDI` and
- by `application pool` (for example `HicariCP` or `c3p0`).

Which way is better? I think `JNDI` is simpler because there is no need for more dependencies to get it to work.

Tomcat [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html) says

> NOTE - The default data source support in Tomcat is based on the DBCP connection pool from the Commons project. However, it is possible to use any other connection pool that implements javax.sql.DataSource, by writing your own custom resource factory

But this [tutorial](http://www.journaldev.com/3531/spring-mvc-hibernate-mysql-integration-crud-example-tutorial) says

> I am using Apache Commons DBCP for connection pooling, but in real life situations, most probably you have connection pooling done by the container and all we need is to provide the JNDI reference details to use.

What is the sense of using `Apache Commons DBCP` dependencies for connection pooling if `Tomcat` itself is using it?

Comment: They are **the same thing**. JDNI is a means to _accessing_ a previously connection pool instance. I really can't recommend using Commons DBCP though.

Comment: @BoristheSpider what is `a previously connection pool instance`? If I configured JNDI then I will use JNDI datasouce polling and the undelying realisation i.e how it is made in Tomcat is the DBCP connection pool from the Commons project. There is other way of using c3p0 for example and no using of JNDI.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to add "configured" to that sentence. So you need to [configure](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html) a JDNI resource; then you access via JDNI in your application. You can configure all sorts of things as JDNI resources, connection pools are just one of them. JDNI pre-dates CDI and DI frameworks, and that would be the recommended approach these days. So JNDI is a method for the container to **manage** resources.